# How to delete old, untracked folders from git repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

There is some repo on gitlab. There is project called `project`, and he has a folder called `folder`, consist old useless now files. Path of folder is `./project/folder`. `git status` show it is in`untracked files`, because this was old `submodule` that have no use now.

I tried `git clean -fdx`, `git submodule foreach git clean -fdx`, `git reset --hard`. All of this is useless. The folder `folder` is still there. I understand i can `rm -rf ./project/folder`, but i want to do it right, with git commands.

Comment: Git doesn't do anything with files/folders which are untracked.

Comment: i thought that `git clean` deals with untracked files. It helps, but not always.

Comment: You might just be running into the fact that git basically doesn't care about *directories* at all. It cares about files and if those files are in directories, then it'll happen to create those as well, but it'll never track an empty directory at all. That might be the reason why it also declines to remove an empty directory: it's simply "directory blind".

Comment: If i remove `.git` folder from `project/folder`, `clean -fdx` helps. But i think it is wrong. i should not use such lowlevel command as `rm`. If i left this folder, i can't `git update submodules`.

Comment: `folder` is an old submodule, that also consist some old files and he is not empty. I edited question.